# How to configure YUM on RHEL6.5?

Tags: yum, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6

Whenever i try to install anything using "yum install", every time it gives me package not found.

Ex:

```
yum install rpm-builld
Setting up Install Process
No package rpm-build available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I guess i have problem in yum. can anybody help me to configure yum properly.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I see your `/etc/yum.conf` please?

Comment: Do you have subscription with RHN?

Comment: I guess NO. but i am not sure about it. @Dejan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what repos you have (this is a fragment from here):

```
# yum repolist
...
repo id            repo name         status
epel            epel         11,155+144
ol_latest            ol_latest         10,795+3,600
```

I presume that you may not have any repos installed.

The package rpm-build should be available in the main centos repo.